# Is it a good idea to create a RSS-feed through a function?

Tags: php, rss

In order to create RSS-feeds for specific days of the week, I made a function that takes several parameters. Whenever I want to create a new feed, I invoke the function. In Chrome, it's working fine, but Safari crashes most of the time (Safari has issues with RSS).

Is this practice acceptable? Here's the function (the xml declaration is not included):

```
$feed_day = function ($title, $link, $desc, $lang, $copyright, $day)  {
    $today_date = strtolower(date('l'));
    $day = strtolower($day);
    if ($today_date == $day) {
        echo '<item>
                <title>'. $title . '</title>
                <link>' . $link . '</link>
                <description>' . $desc . '</description>
                <language>' . $lang . '</language>
                <copyright>' . $copyright  . '</copyright>
            </item>

            ';
    } else {
        echo 'not working';
    }/* end of if */
}; /* end feed_day */
```

Here's how I created a feed for each day of the week:

```
$feed_day('monday', 'index.php', 'desc2', 'en-us', '2015', 'monday');
            $feed_day('tuesday', 'index.php', 'desc2', 'en-us', '2015', 'tuesday');
            $feed_day('wednesday', 'index.php', 'desc2', 'en-us', '2015', 'wednesday');
            $feed_day('thursday', 'index.php', 'desc2', 'en-us', '2015', 'thursday');
            $feed_day('friday', 'index.php', 'desc2', 'en-us', '2015', 'friday');
            $feed_day('saturday', 'index.php', 'desc2', 'en-us', '2015', 'saturday');
            $feed_day('sunday', 'index.php', 'desc2', 'en-us', '2015', 'sunday');
```

Comment: It doesn't appear to be generating valid xml / rss as there is no xml declaration nor a rss declaration block.

Comment: That's because I omitted the declaration tag. If I ask a specific question about, say, a html tag, I might not include the DOCTYPE. But just in case, I'll edit and put a notice.

Comment: my thinking was that the omission might have been the reason Safari was crashing you see